# Algolia Wordpress indexing cause duplicate entries

Tags: wordpress, search, indexing, woocommerce, algolia

I am using Algolia plugin in Woocommerce site for searching, after indexing from woocommerce algolia plugin then in algolia dashboard i see there are **multiple duplicate entries** (everything except object id is same) of same product with **different object id and same post id** . But in wordpress dashboard there is only one entry of the product. This is happening only in some products not all.
Anyone please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allow me to quote the [docs of the Algolia plugin for WordPress](https://community.algolia.com/wordpress/frequently-asked-questions.html):

> **I have more records than I have posts, is that normal?**
>   This is intentional and allows you to fully leverage the Algolia engine.
>
> The plugin takes care of the splitting for you and makes sure that
>   your articles are fully indexed independently from their size.
>
> This means that even if your article is huge and you are searching for
>   a word that is at the very bottom, you will have it as part of the
>   suggested articles.

So to answer your question it is expected that you have multiple records per post. This ensures Algolia provides you with as fast and as relevant results as possible.

You can eventually disable the post splitting by defining a constant in your wp-config.php file: `define( 'ALGOLIA_SPLIT_POSTS', false );`
I only recommend doing so if you are not interested in search inside the content of the posts. In general disabling the post splitting negatively impacts the relevance of the results.

Comment: That's Cool. You're a lifesaver man! Thank you. Is there any performance issue will occur after turning off this ?

Comment: If you turn off the post splitting we truncate the content of the posts.
There should not be any visible performance impact.

If you had already indexed your data, you will probably have to manually delete your indices and do a full re-index afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is there any way to export products to JSON format that support by Algolia ? Then I can manually upload it in algolia dashboard.